# Decrease the complexity of isPalindrome solution?

Tags: java, time-complexity, palindrome

Here is my isPalindrome method

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length()/2; i++){
        int j = s.length() - 1 - i;
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

my teacher says I can decrease the complexity, but I can't see how. I already am only going through half of the string. Is there any way to decrease the complexity of this solution?

Comment: Does he mean runtime complexity or the "complexity" of how your code looks aesthetically?

Comment: Hm, this is quickly turning into "how many ways can I write a palindrome-checking function"?

Comment: I think it might have been declaring the int j every time in the loop. At least that is what it seems like after I have seen these answers.

Comment: @Brandon: frankly, I'd suspect that this code and all of the below answers would get optimized to the same thing after the JIT's had a chance to run.

Comment: It has been confirmed that modern Java implementations do in fact optimize the code so that effectively `s.length()` is outside the loop. I would expect the division by two to be similarly optimized. (Nevertheless, it's not a bad idea to teach people to move expensive operations outside of a loop because often they can't be optimized out.)

Comment: `for (int i = 0, j = s.length()-1; i<j; i++, j--) if (s.charAt(i)!=s.chartAt(j)) return false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome (String str) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = str.length() - 1;

    while (left < right) {
        if (str.charAt(left) != str.charAt(right))
            return false;
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This has the advantage of not calculating the right hand index each time through the loop, especially since it has to access the string length each time (which is constant).

As an aside, I also tend to prefer more meaningful variable names than `s`, `i` and `j` - my basic rule is that, if you have to resort to `j` at all, you're better off naming your counters more expressively (`i` is okay if it's the only counter).

Comment: Depending what is meant by "complexity", one could put ++s inside the str.charAt()s, e.g.  `if (str.charAt(left++) != str.charAt(right--))`

Comment: Thanks for the style tip paxdiablo, and I think your answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think to do would be to store the length of `s`:

```
final int n = s.length();
for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
    int j = n-1-i;
    if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Aside from that, I don't see how you can make it any simpler or more efficient.

Comment: To save a few nanoseconds, you could also store n/2 and n-1 in locals, though the compiler may already be doing that for you...

Comment: Hence the `final int` as a hint to the compiler. But, such micro-optimizations are usually redundant (or even unhelpful) in the face of a good JIT.

Comment: You can also remove `j` altogether and just shove `n-1-i` into `charAt`. But this is also the same kind of micro-optimizations that may be handled automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If he means the complexity of how your code appears aesthetically, then here's a recursive solution:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    if (s.charAt(0) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1)
       return false;
    return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
}
```

If he means the complexity of the algorithm, I am not sure if you could do it any faster. Perhaps you could move substrings onto different cores (using threading) and then combine the results.

EDIT: paxdiablo suggested better code and I re-pended* it in.

Comment: euw, recursion to solve a simple problem like this? that's conceptually more complex, I think...

Comment: I agree. It's an alternative, though. And it might help to understand threading the problem.

Comment: Recursion is a nifty trick for many situations, though I'm not sure this is one of them :-) Still, it's a valid answer. Not a big fan of the `testX` variables, I'd tend to just have `if (charat(0) != charat(len-1)) return false; return isPalindrome(blah blah);`.

Comment: sdasdadas, I've changed it to `- 1` in the substring since I think that's what you meant (it's the end index (index of first character to exclude) rather than the length). One more quibble, on your "appended it in" comment - you would actually append it to, and you didn't so much append as replace. But that's just me being anal retentive and nothing to do with the answer itself, so +1 :-)

Comment: I think the substring should be -2 in the recursive check, because you're moving in one from the furthest character. EDIT: I misunderstood the substring() command.

Comment: "Re-pended"? Now you're just making stuff up :-) But leave it there, for the sake of humour. On the `-1` issue, I don't think so. If the string is "pax" (len=3), you want substring(1,2) which will include starting at 1 ("a") and exclude starting at 2 ("x"), giving you "a".

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the string and it still equals itself, that means it's a palindrome.  Here's how I'd implement it:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

public class PalindromeTest {

    @Test
    public void testTheseArePalindromes() {
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("abccba"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("121"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("Malayalam"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("peeweep"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("123 321"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTheseAreNOTPalindromes() {
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("abc"));
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("123"));
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("123 123"));
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        String lowerIn = input.toLowerCase();
        String reversed = StringUtils.reverse(lowerIn);
        return lowerIn.equals(reversed);
    }

}
```

[The phrases on this page](http://www.rinkworks.com/words/palindromes.shtml) are also palindromes.  Does it have to work on those?  If it does, it's a very simple change:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

public class PalindromeTest {

    @Test
    public void testTheseArePalindromes() {
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("abccba"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("121"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("Malayalam"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("peeweep"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("123 321"));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("A dog, a plan, a canal: pagoda."));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama."));
        assertTrue(isPalindrome("A tin mug for a jar of gum, Nita."));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTheseAreNOTPalindromes() {
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("abc"));
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("123"));
        assertFalse(isPalindrome("123 123"));
    }

    private boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        String removedPunctuation = input.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[.,;: \t]", "");
        String reversed = StringUtils.reverse(removedPunctuation);
        return removedPunctuation.equals(reversed);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for C#, I have not speed tested it.

```
using System;

public class Palindrome
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
    {
        var arr = word.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return word.ToLower() == new string(arr).ToLower() ? true : false;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Palindrome.IsPalindrome("Deleveled"));
    }
}
```