# Trying to copy a SMALLER array into a LARGER array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

This has been driving me insane, on a night where I was supposed to be making large amounts of progress in a massive assignment. Such an elementary-seeming problem has me incredibly embarassed, but I give up. I have tried drawing a picture, I have tried everything I know how to do.

My goal is to copy a smaller array, into a larger empty array, so that the larger array contains zeroes leading up to the beginning of the smaller array.

this.intArray's value: {2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1}
h.intArray's value: {1, 1, 5}

what I WANT hCopy.intArray's value to be: {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5}

Here is my code:

```
    for (int k = h.intArray.length-1;k <= this.intArray.length-1; k++)
    {   

    hCopy.intArray[k] = h.intArray[k - h.intArray.length-1]; 

    }
```

and here is the error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2

Thank you for any assistance lended, I assure you I need it for my sanity's sake.

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  It looks to me that you have 3 arrays.  h.intArray, this.intArray and hCopy.intArray.  If you're copying, why do you have 3?  By looking at your code, I don't understand this.intArrays purpose for existing.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, as I didn't want to copy over my entire ungainly program. h.intArray is of size 4. hCopy.intArray.length and this.intArray.length are both length 7.

Comment: Still a little confused.  My definition of copying an array is to make a copy of it.  To make a copy of something, you don't need 3 things as input.  For example, if I copy a file on my file system, I copy the file, then I paste it, and NOW I've got 2.  But you're starting from 3 and saying you want to copy.  Also, in your example of what hCopy should be, the only thing it has in common with this.intArray is the length.  It's not really using it in any way.

Comment: I think you should re-ask your question and give your inputs and expected outputs.  [Kind of how I did in my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14573943/61624).  Give us a bunch of examples like that `testTheseArePalindromes` method is.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to consider the order of operations when you subtract, you have `k - h.intArray.length - 1`, but I think what you want is `k - (h.intArray.length - 1)`.

But, I think you are exploiting a coincidence that the larger array is twice the size of the smaller array. If it is longer, your code will crash because you will overrun the smaller array. Try this:

```
int start = this.intArray.length - h.intArray.length;
for (int k = start; k < this.intArray.length k++) {
    hCopy.intArray[k] = h.intArray[k - start];
}
```

Note that you aren't clearing the first 3 values to 0 in hCopy, it seems from your question that you need to that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually had the parantheses on that particular subtraction, I simply removed them in my desperation to figure something out. Restoring said parens simply yields ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 instead of -2.

Comment: My overall logic is this: The FOR loop itself must START at the point in the empty, larger array that coincides with the LENGTH of the smaller array, subtracted by 1. Hence, (int k = h.intArray.length-1....). The ENDING CONDITION of this loop is to be the LENGTH of the larger array, subtracted by 1. I then use k as an index in hCopy's array, for storing the value h's array, with the offset k-(h.intArray.length-1). This should work for any n-length array AFAIK...

Comment: Well, sir, I tried your suggested mechanism, and the GOD DAMN **** **** **** **** thing worked. The asterisks are representative of two straight nights with <3 hours of sleep.

Comment: As usual, I overthought it, and all that was necassary was for k to be the DIFFERENCE between the shorter and longer length, as in your code. Thank you so much sir, I would upvote you if would let me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard library way to do it; choose offsets carefully:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    int[] a1 = {2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 1};
    int[] a2 = {1, 1, 5};
    Arrays.fill(a1, 0, a1.length - a2.length, 0);
    System.arraycopy(a2, 0, a1, a1.length - a2.length, a2.length);
```